# kafka consumer API Magic v1 does not support record headers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i was tried post the data to kafka topic..!! but whenever i post the data i was getting error like Magic v1 does not support record headers,

As per @garyrussel suggestion  i was checked kafka client version it was 2.1.0  i tried  below mentioned code also but nothing worked..!!
props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
ProducerRecord<String,String> record=new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic","Key","Value");
producer.send(record);
```

i looked the ProducerRecord it was sending topic,key,value,timestamp,header,partition but in my code i was sending topic,key,value. Is any possible way for avoiding header's in producer records, Any help will be appreciate.. thanks

Comment: are you using `2.1.0`?

Comment: @Deadpool Kafka client version

Comment: What version is the cluster? To use headers, both the client and brokers have to be >= 0.11

Comment: @MickaelMaison i think it's a 0.11 only but my question is any possible way for avoiding headers..!!

Comment: In ProducerRecord i was using topic , key ,value only but how come  headers was sending..??